# Perl Log::Dispatch: Change logging location mid-run?

Tags: perl, logging

I'm using `Log::Dispatch` in a large Mooseified app, via `MooseX::LogDispatch`. My setup is more or less:

```perl
use Moose;
with 'MooseX::LogDispatch';

has log_dispatch_conf => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'HashRef',
    lazy => 1,
    required => 1,
    default => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        return {
            class => 'Log::Dispatch::File',
            min_level => 'debug',
            filename => $self->config->{logfile},
            mode => '>>',
            newline => 1
        };
    },
);
```

Is there any way I can change the location of the log file in the middle of a running process? My specific use case is that I'm processing a number of different large [things], which are passed in at runtime, and I'd like each [thing] to log to its own file. Something like this:

```perl
foreach my $thing (@things) {
    my $logfile = $self->config->{log_base} . $thing->{name} . time() . ".log";
    # do something here to set log location
    $self->logger->info("Start processing " . $thing->{name} . " at " . scalar localtime());
    # process $thing
}
```

Comment: Consider using a new Log::Dispatch object for each case - there isn't really any benefit to reusing the object for different file outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Right. I abandoned `MooseX::LogDispatch` and did it myself.

When we have a new [thing], I just call a trigger to fire a `_set_logger` method:

```perl
sub _set_logger {
    my ($self, $thing) = @_;

    my $log_dir = $self->config->{log_dir}; # /path/to/log_dir
    my $log_file_base = $self->config->{log_file_base}; # e.g. process-thing-log

    my $t = localtime;

    my $logfile = $log_dir . "/" . $log_file_base . $thing->{name} . "-" . $t->ymd . ".log";

    my $logger = Log::Dispatch->new(
    outputs => [
        [ 'File',
          min_level => 'debug',
          filename => $logfile,
          mode => '>>',
          newline => 1,
       ],
     ],
    );

    $self->logger($logger);
    $self->logger->info("Started run at " . scalar localtime);
}
```

Don't know if it's "right", but it's working smoothly.